# high-performance WebGL framework

Tags: performance, frameworks, webgl, mesh

I have a mesh with about 108000 triangles that should be rendered with WebGL.

At the moment I use no framework, just pure WebGL. I've already implemented object recognition via id mapping for picking with callback functionality as well as a basic camera manipulator.

Now I want to switch over to a WebGL framework for maintenance issues.

I've already tried Three.js, but it was to slow for large meshes. Do you know a suitable WebGL framework for large meshes?

EDIT:

I try to render a treemap with nearly 10000 Cube-Nodes and want to do picking on each one(overall goal are 100000 cubes).

Here is the function, that builds the scene:

```
BP2011.Treemap.prototype.buildScene = function() {
  // ... [create scene, camera and lights]
  var nodesParentNode = new THREE.Object3D();
  scene.add(nodesParentNode);
  var nodes = this._nodes;
  for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodesParentNode.add(nodes[i].buildSceneObject());
  }
  this.threejs.nodesParentNode = nodesParentNode;
};
```

And here the function, that builds a single Cube:

```
BP2011.Treemap.Node.prototype.buildSceneObject = function( buildGeometry, buildMaterial ) {
  // ...
  if (buildGeometry || (self.sceneObject && self.sceneObject.geometry === undefined)) {
    // ... [compute cube position and extension]
    geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 
            maxX - minX, 
            maxY - minY, 
            maxZ - minZ);
  } else {
    geometry = this.sceneObject.geometry;
  }

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x4444DD}));

  mesh.position.x = (maxX + minX)/2;
  mesh.position.y = (maxY + minY)/2;
  mesh.position.z = (maxZ + minZ)/2;

  // testing for performance
  mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
  mesh.updateMatrix();
  mesh.geometry.__dirtyVertices = true;
  mesh.geometry.__dirtyElements = true;

  // backwards reference for handling
  this.sceneObject = mesh;
  this.sceneObject.behaviorObject = this;

  return this.sceneObject;
};
```

So I have a parent node with nearly 10000 child nodes, because I didn't know how to do picking with a single object.

If you have any suggestions, how to solve this problem, you're welcome.

I also already took a look at scene.js:
Up to 4000 cubes the performance is really good, but drastically drops at a specific number of cubes(around 4100). So i think i passed some array size there.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I'd like to say that if you are really truly concerned about maximum performance, you probably don't want a framework. The chances that your framework of choice will be optimized for your exact situation are slim, and if you've already got your app rendering with straight WebGL it may be a better idea to simply try and clean up your own code to make it more presentable.

That said, I have a very difficult time believing that Three.js is balking at rendering a few hundred thousand triangles. (Honestly, if you've only got one model it's not THAT much). I'd be curious to know how you are constructing your Three.js scene, as I suspect that there may be some easy optimizations that can be done to get you to the performance level you need.

If you're still looking to try out other frameworks, I'm not sure how they stack up in terms of speed but these are probably worth a look:

- [GLGE](http://www.glge.org/)
- [SceneJS](http://scenejs.org/)
- [J3D](http://www.everyday3d.com/j3d/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Toji that you should probably not turn to a framework if you like to keep speeds up. That said, if you like to get rid of all the WebGL specifics, you could try http://i-am-glow.com which wraps that for you.

To render 10000 objects is no small feat - you'll get CPU bound and even if you just change, let's say, the transform matrix between each draw call. And I think 10000 state changes is really in the upper limit for a normal user's computer. Try to figure out a way to draw several boxes in one call, for example storing the transform matrices and their ID in a floating-point texture, which you sample in the vertex shader. Or, if all boxes are static and could be merged into one big chunk of polygons, use a texture to render their ID.

Comment: what do you mean by "10.000 state changes" here? Are you saying that passing more than 10.000 triangles per render loop is never going fast enough? I think I am hitting that problem in my own project - but all tutorials I've seen so far go for complete rerendering every cycle. Do you know of any published material on other approaches? Thanks

Comment: One state change is, for example, setting a uniform or calling draw.